# When does MongoDB close persistent DB connections?

Tags: mongodb

I ran a few queries w/ the persistent option turned on. I now have a maximum of 8 connections opened (view from the HTTP interface); I was wondering if they'll ever close. Does it hurt to leave all 8 open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it shouldn't hurt to leave them open.  It depends on what application server you're using, but they'll usually be closed after a few requests.  MongoDB accepts up to 20,000 connections.